# FAILURE: Android Build failed with an exception

Tags: javascript, react-native, caching, build.gradle

Whenever I install a new package and run the project, I got the build failed exception.

I am using:

- "react-native": "0.69.5"
- android-gradle-plugin-version: 7.1.1
- gradle-version: 7.5
- Jdk version: corretto-17

```
Issue:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not open cp_proj generic class cache for build file '/Users/dlx-22/Documents/Ambreen/RNApps/Life-Coaching/android/app/build.gradle' (/Users/dlx-22/.gradle/caches/7.5/scripts/7d8fhdqw3s90z8m75i0qt92j0).
   > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 64
```

I clean the cache and ./gradlew. It works sometimes but I got this exception again when installing any new library. How to fix this issue permanently?